# Draw specific area from view to canvas

Tags: java, android, canvas

I have layout and I want to draw specific part from it (not all layout) in PDF page
for example draw from layout0 position  y=150 to y=550
How I can do it?

```
LinearLayout layout0 = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());
                parent.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
if(temp1.getParent() != null) {
                ((ViewGroup)temp1.getParent()).removeView(temp1); 
                layout0.addView(temp1);
 }

temp1.measure(View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(200, View.MeasureSpec.AT_MOST),
                View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));

layout0.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
layout0.measure(View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(200, View.MeasureSpec.AT_MOST),
                View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(400, View.MeasureSpec.AT_MOST));
layout0.layout(0, 0, layout0.getMeasuredWidth(), layout0.getMeasuredHeight());
Canvas canvas = page.getCanvas();

layout0.draw(canvas);
```